# Compare 2 array's of objects and find matching color id's then create a new array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am still learning how to create functions that traverse through arrays. I have a tough one that I can not figure ou
I have two different arrays of objects.

Array 1:

```
const data1 = [
  {
    name: 'I am obj one',
    id: 125,
    category: [18],
    colors: [19, 20],
  },
  {
    name: 'I am obj two',
    id: 111,
    category: [18],
    colors: [19, 20],
  },
];
```

Array 2

```
const data2 = [
  {
    invitation: {
      name: 'Type',
      options: [
        {
          name: 'Show1',
          id: 21,
        },

        {
          name: 'Show2',
          id: 22,
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  {
    color: {
      name: 'Color',

      options: [
        {
          name: 'Gray',
          id: 19,
        },
        {
          name: 'Pink',
          id: 26,
        },
        {
          name: 'Yellow',
          id: 20,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

I am trying to create a new array of data2 with only the "Color" options present in data1 objects.
For this example above, I want to return a new array that looks like this:

```
const data2 = [
  {
    invitation: {
      name: 'Type',
      options: [
        {
          name: 'Show1',
          id: 21,
        },

        {
          name: 'Show2',
          id: 22,
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  {
    color: {
      name: 'Color',
      options: [
        {
          name: 'Gray',
          id: 19,
        },
       {
          name: 'Yellow',
          id: 20,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

Here is my code so far

```
const obj = data1.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.id] = item;
  return acc;
})

data2.forEach(d => {

return d;

});

console.log(data2);
```

caching one of the arrays in an object, it reduces the run time to linear.
Then I am using a forEach method. I am just not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Im not seeing your code. Did you post it? You said you were trying but all you show is the data structures.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my code.

Comment: @Hdjjannana I posed the solution . Please check .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem for you !

Created a set of unique color ids and then filter the data of colors from data2 based on the color ids present in the set

```js
const data1 = [
  {
    name: 'I am obj one',
    id: 125,
    category: [18],
    colors: [19, 20],
  },
  {
    name: 'I am obj two',
    id: 111,
    category: [18],
    colors: [19, 20],
  },
];

const data2 = [
  {
    invitation: {
      name: 'Type',
      options: [
        {
          name: 'Show1',
          id: 21,
        },

        {
          name: 'Show2',
          id: 22,
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  {
    color: {
      name: 'Color',

      options: [
        {
          name: 'Gray',
          id: 19,
        },
        {
          name: 'Pink',
          id: 26,
        },
        {
          name: 'Yellow',
          id: 20,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];

var set = new Set();

data1.forEach(obj => {  obj.colors.forEach(color => set.add(color));}
)


 data2[1].color.options = data2[1].color.options.filter(option => set.has(option.id));
 
 console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am looking to get better at this. Do you know any good resources?

Comment: Good to hear it helped you ! Yes you can go through javascript.info . It is one of the best sites for JS . Also I hope you will not mind upvoting and accepting the answer . This will help other looking for same kind of solution

Comment: Actually I should have mentioned practice also to get better at this